# multi ajax call executed twice on the first call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a timer & i want  every time that the timer return to zero, an Ajax request send to the server and tell me how many coins does the user have and at the same time reduces 1 coin.
It works except the first time that Ajax sends the request to URL
Only for the first time it reduces  2 coins instead of 1 .
I just want to know the reason why this happen

the javascript code:

```
<script>
        var timeout=false;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            match_timer();
        })
    </script>

    <script>
        function match_timer() {
            var n = 5;
            var tm = setInterval(countDown, 1000);

            function countDown() {
                n--;
                document.getElementById('match-timer').innerHTML=n.toString();
                if (n === 0) {
                    clearInterval(tm);
                    get_question();
                    timeout=true;
                }
                if(timeout===true){
                    timeout=false;
                    match_timer();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        function get_question() {

            $("#question").empty();
            $.ajax({
                url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_another_question/',
                method: 'POST',
                data:{
                    "_token":"{{csrf_token()}}",
                },
                success:function (data) {


                           document.getElementById('question').innerHTML=data['title'];

                           $("#coin_balance").html(data['newCoinBalance']);


                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

inside my laravel controller

```
 public function getAnotherMatchQuestion()
    {
        $user_id=auth()->user()->id;
        $user=\App\Models\User::find($user_id);
        $coin=$user->coin_balance;
        $coin-=1;
        $user->coin_balance=$coin;
        $user->save();


        $question_id=mt_rand(1,15612);
        $getMatchQuestion=QuizQuestion::find($question_id)->only(['question']);
        $data=['title'          => $getMatchQuestion['question'],
                   'newCoinBalance' => $coin];

        return response()->json($data);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Ajax is asynchronous operation, meaning, this would execute in a different thread and rest of the code would continue as normal without waiting for ajax call to finish. Double decrement might also be possible if 2 tabs are opened and request comes from both tabs simultaneously. To overcome this, you can make use of [`transactions`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions). So your Laravel code would look like below:

```
public function getAnotherMatchQuestion(){
  try{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $user_id =auth()->user()->id;
    $user = \App\Models\User::find($user_id);
    $coin = $user->coin_balance;
    $coin -= 1;
    $user->coin_balance = $coin;
    $user->save();

    $question_id = mt_rand(1,15612);
    $getMatchQuestion = QuizQuestion::find($question_id)->only(['question']);
    $data = [
               'title' => $getMatchQuestion['question'],
               'newCoinBalance' => $coin
            ];
    DB::commit();
    return response()->json($data);
  }catch(Exception $e){
    DB::rollBack();
    return return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
  }
}
```

**Note that** this would be maintaining consistency of data, meaning number of request made is equal to number of requests served without any data loss.

Comment: I did it but still i have the problem

Comment: @hesmM You call `get_question();` every 5 seconds. Is that correct? Do you have multiple tabs opened?

Comment: yes i want to reduce one coin each time  the timer turns to zero,the code works properly except the first time that the timer becomes 0.    no it's just one tab

Comment: @hesmM What's the value first time in your database? Do you mean value was 5 and after the first request it became 3?

Comment: manually i set the value on 100 but after first request it change to 98 whereas it must be 99 
This problem is only for the first request after that  every thing is ok

Comment: @hesmM Ok, did you check in the network tab of the browser? How many requests did you see? Is there a way I can see your site?

Comment: i checked the network tab,there is only one ajax request for each time the timer turns to zero

Comment: @hesmM Is there a way I can see your site?

Answer (score 0):

1. Doublecheck your network to have only 1 AJAX call at the start
2. Try logging getAnotherMatchQuestion (e.g. to file) with time so you know that it is called as many times as AJAX proceed.
3. in function match_timer you redefine n everytime with call and recoursivelly call match_timer. before it proceeds (1 second delay)

> ```
> var n = 5;
>
> function match_timer
> ```

4. The last: use ajax error for situations when call is not correct.